# How to show the recursive sequence $(x_n)\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_1>1,x_{n+1}=2-1/x_n$ is decreasing? (Please answer base case only!)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm working on Exercise $3.3.2$ from *Introduction to Real Analysis* by Bartle and Sherbert, which says:

> Let $x_1>1$ and $x_{n+1}:=2-1/x_n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Show that $(x_n)$ is bounded and monotone. Find the limit.

First, to get an idea of the behavior of the sequence to see whether it was increasing or decreasing, I took as an example $x_1=2$ and deduced that $x_2=1\frac{1}{2},x_3=1\frac{1}{3},x_4=1\frac{1}{4},$ etc., so it seems the sequence must be decreasing.

So now I'm trying to prove that $(x_n)$ is decreasing by proving the statement $P(n):x_{n+1}\leq x_n$ is true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and I got stuck at the base case, $P(1):x_2\leq x_1$. If at all possible, I'd **only** like help with the **base case** of just the proof of monotonicity so that I can use that support as a springboard to figure out the rest of the problem on my own.

I deduced so far that since $x_1>1,-1/x_1>-1.$ (right?) So then

$$ x_2=2-\frac{1}{x_1}>2-1=1.$$

That only tells me that $x_2>1,$ and I don't think this really helps me show that $x_2\leq x_1.$ (However, this will help me prove that $(x_n)$ is bounded when that time comes...)

I also tried:

$$x_2=2-\frac{1}{x_1}=\frac{2x_1-1}{x_1}<2x_1-1<2x_1$$

But surely $x_2<2x_1$ doesn't imply that $x_2\leq x_1$...

Are there any other ways to show $x_2\leq x_1$?

To be clear, please **only** give me a hint for the base case above -- I want to try to figure out the rest on my own. Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Comment: Hint: $\;x_2 - x_1 = 2 - \left(x_1 + \dfrac{1}{x_1}\right)\,$.

Comment: Ah!! So then $x_2-x_1=2-\left(x_1+\frac{1}{x_1}\right)>2-(1+1)=0$ which implies $x_2>x_1$?

Comment: No, but remember (or prove) that $\,a + \dfrac{1}{a} \ge 2\,$ for any $\,a \gt 0\,$.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: Another way is to note that if you define $y_n := \frac{1}{x_n - 1}$, then $y_{n+1} = y_n + 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By induction $x_n>1$ for all $n$, so $$0<( {x_n}^{1/2}- x_n^{-1/2})^2=x_n-2+1/{x_n} =x_n-x_{n+1}\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to show that $(x_n)$ is bounded, as establishing nice inferior bound will be very usefull in the sequel. In fact, you can prove (by induction) that :

> Fact : for all $n$, we have $1 < x_n $.

Now let us introduce the function $f : x \mapsto 2 - \frac{1}{x}$. We have $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$.
We now have

$$x_{n+1} < x_n \Longleftrightarrow x_{n+1} - x_n < 0 \Longleftrightarrow \\
\boxed{f(x_n) - x_n < 0}$$

Let us introduce $g : x \mapsto f(x) - x$. All we have to show in order to prove that $(x_n)$ is (strictly) decreasing is to show that $g(x_n) < 0$ for all $n$.

Notice that $g$ is differentiable on $[1 ; +\infty[$ with derivative $g'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} - 1$. $g(1) = 0$ and $g$ is decreasing since $g'(x) <0$ for all $1 < x$. Hence, we have that $g(x) < 0$ for all $x > 1$. In particular, $g(x_n) < 0$ for all $n$ QED : **$(x_n)$ is decreasing**.

Since $(x_n)$ is bounded below by $1$ and is decreasing, it has a limit $l := \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ that satisfies $l \geqslant 1$ . Luckily, there is an easy way to compute $l$ :

Since $f$ is continuous, we get $\lim f(x_n) = f(\lim x_n) = f(l)$ whence

$$l = \lim x_n = \lim x_{n+1} = \lim f(x_n) = f(l)$$

i e $g(l) = 0$ whence $\boxed{l = 1}$ by the analysis of $g$ made above.